# If I pull data from Hive, the list is shown empty on first run and only shows after hot restart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

This is my first attempt at a Flutter app after Swift/Android, and having trouble getting data to display on first run of the app.

In my list screen, I build a list using GroupedListView and all is ok if I load a local json file as the datasource, but if I instead pull the exact same data from Hive, the list is shown empty on first run and only shows after hot restart.
Can't see where I am going wrong. In the below code `readJson()` works but `getData()` does not.

```
class venueList extends StatefulWidget {
const venueList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<venueList> createState() => _venueList();
}

class _venueList extends State<venueList> {
List<Venue> _venues = [];

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 //readJson(); 
 getData();
}

// This works
// Future<void> readJson() async {
//   final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/venues.json');
//   final data = await json.decode(response);
//   setState(() {
//     _venues = data["items"];
//   });
// }

// This doesn't
Future<void> getData() async {
final venueBox = await Hive.openBox('venuesBox');
 setState(() {
  _venues = List<Venue>.from(venuesBox.values.toList());
 });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: GroupedListView<Venue, String>(
    elements: _venues,
    groupBy: (Venue v) => v.venueGroup,
    groupComparator: (value1, value2) => value2.compareTo(value1),
    order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
    useStickyGroupSeparators: true,
    separator: Divider(
      height: 1.0,
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
    groupSeparatorBuilder: (String value) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 10.0, 15.0),
        color: kMidBlueColour,
        child: Text(
          value.toUpperCase(),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 26,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              fontFamily: 'SanFranciscoDisplay',
              color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    itemBuilder: (c, Venue v) {
      return ListTile(
        contentPadding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
        leading: Hero(
          tag: v.venueName,
          child: Container(
            child: Image.asset(
              'images/venue1440/' + v.venueImage,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          v.venueTitle.toString().toUpperCase(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: kMidBlueColour,
            fontFamily: 'SanFranciscoDisplay',
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          v.venueAddress,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF4A4A49),
            fontFamily: 'SanFranciscoDisplay',
            fontSize: 18.0,
          ),
        ),
        trailing: const Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                color: Colors.grey,
                size: 50.0,
              ),
        visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: 4, vertical: 0),
        onTap: () {
          
        },
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use FutureBuilder. refer [this article](https://medium.com/nonstopio/flutter-future-builder-with-list-view-builder-d7212314e8c9).

Comment: Thanks, that works, still interested to know why it worked decoding a local json file and not Hive? Would have thought decoding just as time consuming as opening a hive box

Comment: FutureBuilder calls the future function to wait for the result. 
Getting data from localJson is still quick process compare to open Hive box or Rest API call.
Getting data from Rest API or Hive box or Sqflite data is kind of waiting process until data comes that's why futurebuilder needed to tell system to wait.